# Missing out lines in action

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

verbIn a tutorial I've got three fields which supply text to the properties thePlace, theVerb and theNumber

The button action should replace the words ,  and  in a template (with the appropriate properties).

This is the action:

```
-(IBAction) createStory:(id)sender{

theStory.text =[theTemplate.text
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<number>"
                withString:theNumber.text];
theStory.text =[theTemplate.text
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<place>"
                withString:thePlace.text];
theStory.text =[theTemplate.text
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<verb>"
                withString:theVerb.text];
}
```

The problem is that it only acts on the last of the replacements (i.e., in this case only the word verb is replaced by the content of theVerb.

If I change the action to:

```
-(IBAction) createStory:(id)sender{

theStory.text =[theTemplate.text
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<verb>"
                withString:theVerb.text];
    theStory.text =[theTemplate.text
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<number>"
                withString:theNumber.text];
theStory.text =[theTemplate.text
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<place>"
                withString:thePlace.text];

}
```

Only the word place is replaced (with thePlace content)

Why is only the last replace being acted upon and the first two ignored? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
theStory.text =[theTemplate.text
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<number>"
                withString:theNumber.text];
theStory.text =[theTemplate.text
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<place>"
                withString:thePlace.text];
```

Both times your code changes the string in theTemplate.text and assigns it to theStory.text.

Your code doesn't use the previously changed text. It uses the text from the template.

Maybe you should try something like this:

```
theStory.text =[theTemplate.text
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<number>"
                withString:theNumber.text];
theStory.text =[theStory.text
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<place>"
                withString:thePlace.text];
```

In this case the second line changes the text that you got back from the first line.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response @fluchtpunkt. That seems to make sense. I'll give it a try.